# ADS AEL: operand: ee_boolparameter value required whenever I try to compare voltages

Tags: error, ads

I'm not very experienced with Keysight's Advanced Design System. I am trying to use the `if` statement in my user-defined function to compare two volage values and take an action based on the outcome.
During debugging, if I use constants as the function parameters, it works fine. But the moment I use the actual voltage value (from the simulation), I get the error message

> operand: ee_boolparameter value required

Below is a test function:

```
    defun Test(argument, argument2)
{
    decl x = argument;
    decl y = argument2;


    if(x == y)
    {
        return "Equal";
    }
    else 
    {
        return "Not Equal";
    }
}
```

Now, if I use constants as the arguments passed in the equation, it works fine, but if I use the values I got via simulation, it reports the error (see the attached images).The first image is the function with constant values passed as paramters. [image: function with constants] The next two are with the simulated values[image: function with simulated variable] [image: error distcription]

I know it is a simple problem, but I've had sleepless nights over this, as my work is dependent on it. Please can anyone help tell me what to do?

Comment: looks like "return x" would return the wrong type, if ever executed... If this is a compiled language, that would be a compile time error

Comment: Thanks @Brian for pointing that put. I've removed that line. It's redundant and can never be reached. However, the problem still persists.

Comment: Well the error says "ee_boolparameter value required". Are "Equal" and "Not Equal" legal values for whatever a ee_boolparameter is? Most booleans I know are restricted to the values TRUE or FALSE, or in more perverse languages, 0 or 1.

Comment: Legal values for boolean in ADS are TRUE, FALSE or 1,0.
The issue, however, is not about the return type (can be anything), but the arguments fed into the function. It expects me to enter either TRUE or FALSE as parameters. But what I have are not boolean values. I don't know if that helps to explain it better.

Comment: I suspect your function needs to return TRUE or FALSE. It's returning something else that isn't TRUE or FALSE. Using constants would allow the result to be pre-determined (aka "constant folding") such that "test" may never even be called, so hiding the problem. But I'll have to bow out here and leave this for someone familiar with this odd language.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Truly, the error has nothing to do with what is returned. I appreciate your efforts. I still await a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question and have also finally come up with the answer: The problem was the datatype that was supplied to the function from the simulation. 
The solution to the problem is to treat the voltage values as arrays, not as constants. That way, you can explicitly reference individual members of the array and use them in the comparison.
Problem solved.